# Converting 30+ GB of TIFF files into SPDFs

Tags: pdf, conversion, tiff

Any ideas on how to do it?

I know ImageMagick will batch convert them to a PDF but Id like a searchable PDF. Adobe Acrobat pro seems to do it but its fairly slow and produces an image SPDF which seems bulky.

Comment: Searchable PDF?  You're converting image files--how will being searchable make any difference?

Comment: If by bulky you means the PDF is large, Acrobat not only has the normal Optimize but it has an Optimize a scanned PDF.  One of the things it does is removes the background.  The can save space if you are scanning text documents.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that might get useful: http://tfischernet.wordpress.com/2008/11/26/searchable-pdfs-with-linux/
Are you trying to put the 30GB of tiff into one pdf?